# How to shows that $f(x)=x, x\in[0,1]-C,f(x)=1,x\in C$ is an upper function and is Lebesgue integrable where $C$ is a Cantor set?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How to show that $f(x)=x, x\in[0,1]\setminus C,f(x)=1,x\in C$ is an upper function and is Lebesgue integrable where $C$ is a Cantor set?

Comment: What does "upper function" mean?

Comment: @Arthur $f(x)$ is upper function if there is increasing sequence of step functions converging to $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $m(C)=0$ and $f \geq 0$ we have that $f=x$ a.e on

Thus $\int_0^1 f=\int_0^1 x dx =\frac{1}{2}<+\infty$

Thus the function is Lebesgue integrable.

Also as a simpler proof note that $f$ is measurable and non-negative and  bounded by $1$ so it is integrable.